# Simple React API requests with Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to create a wrapper for API calls and I think that i'm missing something. The promise stores the posts in `this.post` but I cannot figure out the correct way to return the data.

So far I have tried this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const CallumAPI = {
  posts: [

  ],
  all: function() {
    axios.get('http://callum.dev/api/posts')
      .then(res => {
        this.posts = res.data.posts;
      })
    return this.posts;
  }
}

export default CallumAPI
```

In my wrapper I am trying to return the posts so that in my component I can just list them all out. Here's the component code:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    {
      CallumAPI.all().map(p => (
        <li key={p.id}>
          <Link to={'/post/${p.slug}'}>{p.name}</Link>
        </li>
      ))
    }
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `CallumAPI.all().then(results => results.map(...))` ?

Comment: Where does that go? I tried changing my code to this `CallumAPI.all().then(results => results.data.posts.map(p => (` and it just caused errors

Comment: `axios.get` is an async call. So `this.posts` was returned as an empty array before the promise finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly access the data from `axios`, as it will always return the `promise`, so you need either a `callback function` or need to access it via `then` once data is available.

Here is what you can do :

Change CallumAPI Like this :

```
const CallumAPI = {
  posts: [

  ],
  all: function() {
    return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users') // change your api url
      .then(res => {
        this.posts = res.data;
        return this.posts; // return data so we can use
      })
  }
}
```

And Component like this :

```
componentWillMount() {
    CallumAPI.all().then(posts => {
        console.log(posts);
        this.setState({posts}); // set state on data fetch so UI will render 
    });
}

render() {
    const { posts } = this.state;
    return (
        <ul>
        { posts.map(p => (
            <li key={p.id}>
                { p.name }
            </li>
            )) }
        </ul>
    );
}
```

Here is **[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-axios-api)**

Comment: My code to render the component looks different to yours, mine looks like this `const ListPosts = () => (`

Comment: @Callum, please check the Working demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-axios-api , it will clear all your doubts

Comment: Ok I think I understand it better now

Answer (score 0):

`axios` request is an async call and you are returning the array even before the promise is resolved. Also you shouldn't have a async request in your render function. You would rather want it to called once and store the result. Have your `async` request in the `componentDidMount` function.

You could change your `all` function to receive a `callback` function and pass the response to it.

```
const CallumAPI = {
  posts: [

  ],
  all: function(cb) {
    axios.get('http://callum.dev/api/posts')
      .then(res => {
        cb(res.data.posts);
      })
  }
}


componentDidMount() {
    CallumAPI.all(this.updateResult);
}

updateResult = (res) => {
    this.setState({res})
}

render() {
<div>
  <ul>
    {
      this.state.res.map(p => (
        <li key={p.id}>
          <Link to={`/post/${p.slug}`}>{p.name}</Link>
        </li>
      ))
    }
  </ul>
</div>
}
```

Comment: My code to render the component looks different to yours, mine looks like this `const ListPosts = () => (`

Comment: In that case you need to convert your `ListPost` function as a class component